# List all missing dependencies in maven

Tags: maven

I have a maven project built from many modules. I'm not using official maven repository for downloading dependencies, but my company's.

Unfortunately, our nexus does not have all required dependencies.

Is there a way in maven to run a command, which does not stop, when dependency cannot be found, but continues and provides a list of missing dependencies after the execution is finished?

Comment: Such a command seems impossible to build because of transitive dependencies. Isn't the company Nexus configured to proxy Maven central?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe unfortunately not. Currently I'm excluding modules with `-pl`, but I hoped for better way.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The best thing I could image would be to run `mvn dependency:list` against MavenCentral and then check for each element of the list (by a script, maybe) if it is available in your company.